# Unable to use the Python Data Frame method "iloc" on a Data Frame created in pyspark's SQLContext

Tags: python, apache-spark

After loading a dataset as DataFrame in pyspark's SQLContext, unable to use the Python DataFrame property of 'iloc' on it. Does a DataFrame created in SQLContext of pyspark behave differently and expect different methods than the python DataFrame ?

```
Error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Full Code: Just loading a data_set and using a custom function to split the datset in to two sets named test_set and train_set

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_set = sqlContext.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('/FileStore/tables/69qouxnt1504605761640/AirQualityUCI.csv')

# Split train and test sets
def split_train_test(data, test_ratio):
    length = data.count()
    shuffled_indices = np.random.permutation(length)
    test_set_size = int(length * test_ratio)
    test_indices = shuffled_indices[:test_set_size]
    train_indices = shuffled_indices[test_set_size:]
    return data.iloc[train_indices], data.iloc[test_indices]

train_set, test_set = split_train_test(data_set, 0.2)
```

Comment: Use the [randomSplit method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit). Welcome to the site!